# numpy concatenate with axis -1 visualize with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Given 2 images, `axis = 0` and `axis = 1` in `np.concatenate` concatenate images in rows and columns, respectively.

but `axis = -1` changes the channel of the concatenated image to **6** which leads to the following error while visualizing using `matplotlib`:

```
raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

The code I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img_A = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img_B = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

conc_img = np.concatenate((img_A, img_B), axis=-1)

print "shape:\t imgA={},imgB={},conc_img={}".format(img_A.shape, img_B.shape, conc_img.shape)
plt.imshow(conc_img)
plt.show()
```

print function returns:

```
shape: imgA=(375, 500, 3),imgB=(375, 500, 3),conc_img=(375, 500, 6) # <<-- channel is changed to 6
```

How can I visualize this concatenated image?

Comment: Will you please share these two images (1.jpg and 2.jpg), if you can?

Comment: As per matplotlib imshow docs (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) .. you can visualize only 3 channels or 4 channels (4th channel being alpha/transparency). "Supported array shapes are:

(M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a colormap.
(M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).
(M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e. including transparency." ... What is the end purpose of having 6 channels?

Comment: Do you understand why you get the size 6 dimension?  If 3 values represent colors, what is 6 supposed to do?  What kind of visualization do you expect?

Comment: Rereading your question, I'm not sure I understand... what do you expect the resulting image to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You more or less answered your own question. If you concatenate on `axis=-1` (the last axis) then you're concatenating on the RGB channel. As you say, this results in 6 channels, and images can only have 1, 3, or 4 channels.

Try:

```
conc_img = np.concatenate((img_A, img_B), axis=1)
```

You'll get an array of shape `(375, 1000, 3)`. Or change `axis` to 0 to concatenate on the first axis and get `(750, 500, 3)`.

Or do you mean something other than 'concatenate'? If you want the result to have shape `(375, 500, 3)` then you are looking for a different function.